# Delphi rest and authentication

Tags: rest, delphi, authentication

I have a web .NET service. I can connect this web service from web browsers.
If I write service address first web browser ask username and password than service is connected.

If I connect this web service with `delphi`. There is error message:

> Error message is "401 Unauthorized"

I am using:

- RESTResponse1
- RESTRequest1
- RESTClient1 and HTTPBasicAuthenticator 1.
- HTTPBasicAuthenticator1 has username and password and RestClient add Authenticator.

But I can not connect web service
How can I connect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out the reason for the missing (or wrong) authentication you can use the developer / debug mode in most web browsers. You could also use Wireshark or a HTTP proxy.

Check the response headers of the server. They include information about all supported authentication modes (see [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2))